# EIntfCastError 'Interface not supported'

Tags: delphi-10.3-rio

I am trying to save and load an xml file from my hard disk drive by calling the above code

```
  TS.SaveToFile(Def_Response_XmlFile, TEncoding.UTF8);
  XMLResponseDoc := LoadResponseDoc(Def_Response_XmlFile);
```

But when I  called the following function

```
    function LoadResponseDoc(const FileName: string): IXMLResponseDoc;
begin
  ShowMessage('' +FileName);
  ShowMessage('' +TXMLResponseDoc);
  ShowMessage('' +TargetNamespace);
  Result := LoadXMLDocument(FileName).GetDocBinding('ResponseDoc', TXMLResponseDoc, TargetNamespace) as IXMLResponseDoc;
  ShowMessage('arrive here');
end;
```

I took as response the mentioned error.Any ideas what am I doing wrong?

Comment: What is TS declared as? What does the saved XML actually look like? Perhaps the load is failing, or the XML doesn't match what `TXMLResponseDoc` is expecting.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help Remy! My bug was that  I didn't initialized XMLResponseDoc  with NewRequestedDoc  command.